# Generate MD5 hash in Java -Output 16 character

Tags: java

I have created MD5 hash.Its working fine now.I want output in 16 character.Current Code is returning 32 characters.

This is my code:

```
    try {
            String text = "Hello World";
            MessageDigest msg = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            msg.update(text.getBytes(), 0, text.length());
            String digest1 = new BigInteger(1, msg.digest()).toString(16);
            System.out.println("MD5: " + digest1.length());
            System.out.println("MD5: " + digest1);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AndroidActivationView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Where I want to change it.

How can i get the 16 character output.?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Well... MD5 is a 128-bit hash, that is to say, 16 bytes. It can be represented in 32 hexadecimal characters. Do you want the raw data as an ASCII string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cut the string to length: `digest1 = digest1.substring(0, 16);`

MD5 outputs 16 bytes. If you encode it in hexadecimal, its 32 characters. If you encode it in base-64 it's 24 characters. Base-85 will squeeze it into 20 characters. There's no well-known encoding that is one character per byte.

Comment: Would it waste computing resources by truncating string?

Comment: @Alex Using `BigInteger` solely as a means to hex-encode a byte array isn’t optimal; a function dedicated to hex-encoding could skip some of the checks performed by `BigInteger` initialization, and also accept offset and length parameters to select a sub range of a byte array.