# How to convert a variable length string to a 16 character string?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I need to convert a variable length string of length 60 - 100 characters into a 16 character unique string. Please note that the input will be unique as well. Is there some existing hashing algorithm i can use? Or is there another way this can be achieved?

Comment: How about doing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499550/generate-md5-hash-in-java-output-16-character ? The solution is agnostic to hash function used, so you could use a better algorithm than MD5 if you're concerned at all about security.

Comment: That is not how hashes work. You are looking for compression. Compressing 100 characters into 16 is highly data-specific. You say the input is "unique"; is it predetermined? That is, do you know what every input value will ever be? If not, you will probably not be able to achieve what you want.

Please post more information about your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable length 60 string unique can be a lot more than 16 length strings.

So a general, good algorithm is not possible. It is like generate from each letter unique ( a-z) a digit (0-9)

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions don't have unique outputs by the pigeonhole principle. If you there are actually less than < 2^16 distinct inputs, it is *possible*, but this is not a design goal of any hash functions I know of, and you'd have to create the hash function with knowledge of *all* inputs. So you'd have to emulate it. The simplest scheme that's reasonable efficient seems to be:

- Keep an associative array from input strings to integers
- When hashing a string, look it up in the associative array

  - If it's in the associative array, return the associated value
  - Else, let `map[input] = map.entry_count()` and return that

This assigns a unique integer to every input, and does hashing in either O(1) expected time or O(log n) time, but it takes some space. You can then convert this integer into a string if you must, for example with base64 encoding, hexadecimal notation, or by interpreting it as string in some character encoding (though you have to take care to end up with valid strings). Each of those gives you far more than 10^16 outcomes, and makes the strings less likely to be confused for numbers.